# Koma-Script areaset and footlines

Tags: koma-script, typearea

It seems like that the options `footlines` and `footheight` are ignored if `areaset` is used. Consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass[footheight=30pt]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadings
\cfoot{foo \\ bar}

\areaset{17cm}{25cm}

\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}
```

Although `footheight=30pt` is set I get the following warning if compiled:

```
Package scrlayer-scrpage Warning: \footheight to low.
(scrlayer-scrpage)                At least 28.99998pt needed,
(scrlayer-scrpage)                but only 18.125pt found.
(scrlayer-scrpage)                I'll enlarge \footheight, for further
(scrlayer-scrpage)                processing, but you should do this yourself,
(scrlayer-scrpage)                e.g., setting typearea's option
(scrlayer-scrpage)                `footheight=28.99998pt'.
(scrlayer-scrpage)                I'll also increase \footskip on input line 13
```

The problem still persists if `footlines=2.1` is used. Any ideas what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `\areaset` ignores options `headheight`, `headlines`, `footheight` and `footlines`. This is documented in the KOMA-Script manual [scrguien.pdf](http://www.komascript.de/scrguien) (English) and [scrguide.pdf](http://www.komascript.de/scrguide) (German). And in Part II of the KOMA-Script manual you can find option `areasetadvanced`, that changes the behaviour. Nevertheless there are still some difference in details of the margin calculation used by `\typearea` and `\areaset`. Have a look at the manual for more information.

```
\documentclass[footheight=30pt,areasetadvanced]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}

\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadings
\cfoot{foo \\ bar}

\areaset{17cm}{25cm}

\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes that fixed it. Thanks for letting me know!